# How to retrieve specific element from a set based on an element with same hash?

Tags: python, set, hashtable

Consider a class with several fields and a custom `__eq__()` and `__hash__()` methods considering some of those fields.

The `__eq__()` and `__hash__()` are performed on the same fields, although there are other fields that are not involved, but are useful for carrying information.

I have a class instance A, which has some information. Then I have a dummy instance B, with no information but the same hash as A and it applies that

```
A == B
```

I want to retrieve the old instance A from the set (somehow instantly based on the hash), modify the information within (not interfering with the hash nor equality) and put it back into the set.

How can I do that? Is it possible without having to implement a something special? I dont want to implement the whole hashtable data-structure. Also I cannot use dict, cause I have no labeling system other than hashes, which can be shared between different instances (generally)

Comment: Use a class-wide dict where the key is the hash and value is a list of all the instances with that hash.

Comment: Otherwise you'll have to search the set looking for an element with the same hash.

Comment: If two instances have the same hash and are considered equal, the set can only hold one of them.

Comment: @Barmar A set can hold multiple items with same hash if they aren't equal.

Comment: @MichaelButscher But he says that the equality operator uses the same criteria.

Comment: @Barmar I understood it that way that this isn't generally true but only for some dummy objects representing the real objects in some way.

Comment: @MichaelButscher I edited my comment to reflect his specific conditions.

Comment: I recommend a dict where key and value are the A-like objects. Simple "get(B)" on the dict will then return A.

Comment: I hoped for a solution which would not require me to implement my own datastructure. If I was able to retrieve at least the list of elements with the same hash, it would have helped me. It seem though, that Python does not support that approach.